# How do I make hierarchy of objects from two alternating classes?

Tags: c#, xml, generics

Here's the scenario:

I have two classes ("Page" and "Field"), that are descended from a common class ("Pield").
They represent tags in an XML file and are in the following hierarchy:

```
<page>
    <field>
        <page>
           ...
        </page>
        ...
    </field>
    ...
</page>
```

I.e.: Page and Field objects are in a hierarchy of alternating type (there may be more than one Page or Field to each rung of the hierarchy).

Every Field and Page object has a parent property, which points to the respective parent object of the other type. This is not a problem unless the parent-child mechanism is controlled by the base class (Pield), which is shared by the two descended classes (Page and Field).

Here is one try, that fails at the line "Pield child = new Pield(pchild, this);":

```
class Pield<T>
{

    private T _pield_parent;

    ...

    private void get_children() {
        ...
                        Pield<Page> child = new Pield<Page>(pchild, this);
        ...
    }
    ...
}


class Page : Pield<Field> {
    ...
}

class Field : Pield<Page>
{
     ...
}
```

Any ideas about how to solve this elegantly?

Best,

Millicent

Comment: What is pchild? Why it fails?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you don't need inheritance, rather containment. A field is not **a type of page**, it is **contained within a page**. Something like:

```
class Page
{
    Field Parent {get;set;}
    IEnumerable<Field> Children {get;set;}
}
class Field 
{
    Page Parent {get;set;}
    IEnumerable<Field> Children {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I pretty much agree. But as per OP requirements, I'd add a Parent property to both Page and Field. I'd also turn the Page/Field properties into List<Page/Field>. But you have the main point.

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to register, but I've got no idea how to reply to individual posts, so I'll just write the reply here.

First off, thanks for the replies! There's some useful tips in there, especially from you, ohadsc.

I've solved the problem by removing the parent class ("Pield") and putting all of the respective code into the two child classes. Even though the idea behind both classes was broadly similar, the code was split up between the two in the parent class anyway.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Millicent